# Ace Editor does not work in Iframe (react-frame-component)

Tags: iframe, ace-editor, react-portal, react-frame-component

tl;dr [Demo of Issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-component-frame-ace-editor-grvb0?file=/src/index.js)

I'm attempting to integrate [Ace Editor](https://ace.c9.io/) in an iframe via React 16. I am using the [react-ace](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace) component library, though this issue exists if I implement the editor natively as well.

Although everything mostly works when I wrap the editor in [react-frame-component](http://react-frame-component), I cannot select highlight text which makes the editor unusable. I suspect this may have to do with the fact that `react-frame-component` is implemented with Portals, but I'm not sure exactly what the issue is.

I've replicated the issue [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-component-frame-ace-editor-grvb0?file=/src/index.js). I don't think this problem exists if I loaded the component with a regular `<iframe src />` from another domain.

Answer (score 0):

react-frame-component keeps the code in the parent window, and adds elements into an iframe, which confuses mouse handling code in ace to add event listeners to a wrong document 
adding `var document = el.ownerDocument` before
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.4.10/lib/ace/lib/event.js#L111 would help.

Comment: I think you're right, any ideas on how to circumvent this without forking the library? react-frame-library has `FrameContextConsumer` (https://github.com/ryanseddon/react-frame-component#accessing-the-iframes-window-and-document) and I can always retrieve the iframe document. Not sure how to repoint it with a 3rd party library though.

Comment: best way is to make a pull request to ace, monkeypatching `ace.require("ace/lib/event").capture` may work as a temporary solution